# Assign Application Insights cloud_RoleName to Windows Service running w/ OWIN

Tags: owin, azure-application-insights

I have an application built from a series of web servers and microservices, perhaps 12 in all.  I would like to monitor and, importantly, map this suite of services in Applications Insights.  Some of the services are built with Dot Net framework 4.6 and deployed as Windows services using OWIN to receive and respond to requests.

In order to get the instrumentation working with OWIN I'm using the [ApplicationInsights.OwinExtensions](https://github.com/marcinbudny/applicationinsights-owinextensions) package.  I'm using a single instrumentation key across all my services.

When I look at my Applications Insights Application Map, it appears that all the services that I've instrumented are grouped into a single "application", with a few "links" to outside dependencies.  I do not seem to be able to produce the "Composite Application Map" the existence of which is suggested here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-app-map.

I'm assuming that this is because I have not set a different "RoleName" for each of my services.  Unfortunately, I cannot find any documentation that describes how to do so.  My map looks as follow, but the big circle in the middle is actually several different microservices:

[image: App Insights Map]

I do see that the OwinExtensions package offers the ability to customize some aspects of the telemetry reported but, without a deep knowledge of the internal structure of App Insights telemetry, I can't figure out whether it allows the RoleName to be set and, if so, how to accomplish this.  Here's what I've tried so far:

```
        appBuilder.UseApplicationInsights(
            new RequestTrackingConfiguration
            {
                GetAdditionalContextProperties = 
                    ctx =>
                        Task.FromResult(
                            new [] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("cloud_RoleName", ServiceConfiguration.SERVICE_NAME) }.AsEnumerable()
                        )
            }
        );
```

Can anyone tell me how, in this context, I can instruct App Insights to collect telemetry which will cause a Composite Application Map to be built?

Answer (score 1):

The following is the overall doc about `TelemetryInitializer` which is exactly what you want to set additional properties to the collected telemetry - in this case set Cloud Rolename to enable application map.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-api-filtering-sampling#add-properties-itelemetryinitializer

Your telemetry initializer code would be something along the following lines...

```
public void Initialize(ITelemetry telemetry)
{

if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName))
            {
                // set role name correctly here.
                telemetry.Context.Cloud.RoleName = "RoleName";
            }
}
```

Please try this and see if this helps.

Comment: I'm using the TelemetryInitializer supplied by the ApplicationInsights.OwinExtension package.  If I define my own, is that additive?

Comment: Does the initializer in ApplicationInsights.OwinExtension package set rolename?

Comment: TelemetryInitializers are run one by one in the order defined. Typically they don't set a property if already set. (unless there is a need to do so)

Comment: No, the one in OwinExtension does not appear to be setting the role name (or perhaps is setting it the same way for all the processes I've added it to).  That's why I'm hoping to use the configuration method to do so.  But, I"ll look into writing my own initializer.  Seems to be a lot of complexity for something that could easily be set in the .config file!

Comment: Ok. Can you check some of the telemetry items in analytics and tell me what are the role names already populated? If no initializers are present to populate the role name, i think its set to the machine name.